# Why cProfile module doesn't work with unittest?

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing, cprofile

I would to use cProfile module to profile my unit tests. But when I run

```
python -mcProfile mytest.py
```

I got 'Ran 0 tests in 0.000s'. Here is the source code of mytest.py

```
import unittest

class TestBasic(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo(self):
        assert True == True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I've tested with other more complex unittests as well. Always got 'Ran 0 tests' if I run it with cProfile. Please help.

**UPDATE:** My OS is MacOS 10.7 with built-in python 2.7. The same code works properly on ubuntu.

Comment: works for me under Ubuntu - python2.6/2.7 :) Did you try with the `Profile` module only ?

Comment: Thanks, Julien. Just tested on ubuntu and it works. Looks like its a platform specific issue. It doesn't work on MacOS 10.7 with built-in python 2.7.

Comment: I guess you never found a way to make it work on Mac OS X?

Comment: I realize that this question is kind of old, but it does not seem to be specific to OS X after all: I can reproduce the problem in the question with Ubuntu 13.04 and Python 2.7.4. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer either.

Answer (score 18):

You have to initialize the cProfiler in the Constructor of the test, and use the profile data in destructor -- I use it like that:

```
from pstats import Stats
import unittest

class TestSplayTree(unittest.TestCase):
    """a simple test"""

    def setUp(self):
        """init each test"""
        self.testtree = SplayTree (1000000)
        self.pr = cProfile.Profile()
        self.pr.enable()
        print "\n<<<---"

    def tearDown(self):
        """finish any test"""
        p = Stats (self.pr)
        p.strip_dirs()
        p.sort_stats ('cumtime')
        p.print_stats ()
        print "\n--->>>"

    def xtest1 (self):
        pass
```

In case that a test waits for input, one needs to call `self.pr.disable()` before that call, and re-enable it afterwards.

If you prefer `pytest` the method names are a bit different:

```
import cProfile
import time

class TestProfile:
    """ test to illustrate cProfile usage """

    def setup_class(self):
        self.pr = cProfile.Profile()
        self.pr.enable()

    def teardown_class(self):
        self.pr.disable()
        self.pr.print_stats(sort="tottime")

    def test_sleep(self):
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Still didn't work for me when I wanted to use flask test clients.

Comment: FYI, the Stats class is available via `from pstats import Stats`

Comment: Is `self.testtree = SplayTree (1000000)` essential here?

Comment: I copied and pasted from my implementation of splay trees, very old. I did it about 3 years ago I think. Anyway, my implementation works well. If you really need, I may open the archives and see.

Comment: No need for `self.testtree = SplayTree (1000000)`. Or you need to provide import for it

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, which asked why it doesnt work from the command line

Answer (score 13):

Specifying the module explicitly fixed this for me. That is, replacing...

```
    unittest.main()
```

...(which tried to auto-discover what tests it should be running) with...

```
    unittest.main(module='mytest')  # if in 'mytest.py', or as appropriate for your filename/module
```

...allowed proper profiling as `python -m cProfile mytest.py`.

Comment: Just as as explanation of this idea:
By default, unittest.main() looks for unit TestCase objects in the '__main__' module.
So when we run it over cProfile module name is differ, and when we define explicit name in
    unittest.main(module='mytest')
 it works

Comment: works, and by far the least intrusive and complicated of the answers.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why, but explicitly creating and running a test suite seems to work.  I added `time.sleep(2)` to show something definitive in the stats.

```python
import time
import unittest

class TestBasic(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        assert True == True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestBasic)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Running in bash, only keeping the first 10 lines, we can see `{time.sleep}` was the longest running call:

```
~ $ python -m cProfile -s tottime so.py | head -n10
testFoo (__main__.TestBasic) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.003s

OK
         1084 function calls (1072 primitive calls) in 2.015 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    2.003    2.003    2.003    2.003 {time.sleep}
        1    0.002    0.002    0.003    0.003 case.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.003    0.003 collections.py:11(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    2.015    2.015 so.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.010    0.010 __init__.py:45(<module>)
```